# Swift Icon badge number exclamation mark

Tags: ios, swift, message

Is there a way to set the icon badge to an exclamation mark?
Messages uses this feature if a message could not be send, but I'm not able to find something about this.

Comment: No, you can only badge with a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you cannot set the app's icon badge text to anything other than a number. What you have seen in the messages app is only one of the *"privileges"* of the apps built by ***Apple***, to give their users a better experience. But for matters of security, ***Apple*** does not allow developers to do that, because who knows in what way a dev will program his app to start spamming with unwanted messages in the badges of the app.

Instead of that, you can just put a normal badge number and send a `local notification` with the desired text to catch the user's attention.

Hope it helps!